# Insert row and preserve formulas on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet that updates itself daily. For simplicity, let's say I generate a number every noon, and at night the spreadsheet is supposed to copy the number into a log column, and show the sum of all stored values for this column (there are actually several columns, and their number might grow in the future). With my current implementation, the sum formula is updated automatically, and thus keeps saving only the values previously available. I wish I could prevent this behavior.

Example:

The spreadsheet reads:

```
Total     1
Today     2
History 
1/29/2014 1
```

Tomorrow, before I update it, it should be:

```
Total     3
Today     
History 
1/30/2014 2
1/29/2014 1
```

The formula I inserted on "Total" line is:

```
=sum(B4:B)
```

Basically, the code I've made for the script contains:

```
//Inserts a new line to compose history log:
sheet.insertRowsAfter(firstHystoryLine-1, 1);
```

And after the script is run, the formula is updated to

```
=sum(B5:B)
```

Therefore my problem.

Comment: I've found a suitable workaround solution by copying values only:
    var todayCol = sheet.getRange("E2:E7");
    todayCol.copyTo(sheet.getRange("F2:F7"), {contentsOnly:true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can add in your code

```
sheet.getRange("B1").setFormula("=sum(b4:b)")
```

This will reset your formula correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Sum(b3:b). Inserting a row should then not affect the formula.

Comment: Not sure I understood your point correctly, but I couldn't make it work. Using lowercase didn't change anything. Not using the equal sign did prevent the number from changing, but the formula is displayed in the cell instead of the result.

Comment: Sorry you need the equal sign for it it's a formula so =sum(b3:b)

Comment: The suggestion is to start the sum from B3 onwards. When a new row is inserted, the formula doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

set your field to be =Sum(B$4). Using the dollar sign should prevent it from sliding. If you were adding in columns as well you'd want to do =Sum($B$4).

Comment: Didn't work for me. The sheet actually changed to =Sum($B$5:B), regardless of the $ sign. Even with a single cell (=Sum($B$$)) it does increment the number.